# android - sayyam/carouselview dynamically change Page Count

Tags: java, android, github, view

I am using [CaruselView](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview) project on github, and I want dynamically change the `PageCount`, and I didn't find anything about this.

Here is the code sample:

```
public class SampleCarouselViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CarouselView carouselView;

    int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_2, R.drawable.image_3, R.drawable.image_4, R.drawable.image_5};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_carousel_view);

        carouselView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.carouselView);
        carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);

        carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);
    }

    ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
            imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
        }
    };

}
```

Maybe dynamically reset the count and set the new count? any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the carousel's parent before change size, than you have to reassign it to the carousel.

```
if (carouselView != null) {
    parentView = carouselView.getParent();
    if (parentView != null && parentView instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup g = (ViewGroup) parentView;
        g.removeView(carouselView);
    }
}
carouselView.setPageCount(newSize);

if (parentView != null && parentView instanceof ViewGroup) {
    ViewGroup g = (ViewGroup) parentView;
    g.addView(carouselView);
}
```